# javascript photo gallery using image onclicks and div containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, onclick

I am trying to create a simple javascript photo gallery. First I used thumbnails of the images I wanted to use in the HTML. The HTML looks like this

```
            <div id="imgs">
               <img onClick="gallery()" src="images/photo25thumbnail.jpg">
               <img onClick="gallery()" src="images/photo43thumbnail.jpg">
               <img onClick="gallery()" src="images/photo46thumbnail.jpg">
               <img onClick="gallery()" src="images/photo47thumbnail.jpg">
               <img onClick="gallery()" src="images/photo61thumbnail.jpg">
             </div>
       <div id="display">

        <div>
       </body>
        </html>
```

So when the user clicks on the image it is supossed to trigger the function gallery. Here is my javascript code

```
                function gallery()

 {
var img1 = document.getElementById("display")
.innerHTML="<a href='#'><img src='images/photo25.jpg'></a>";
var img2 = document.getElementById("display")
.innerHTML ="<a href='#'><img src='images/photo43.jpg'></a>";
var img3 = document.getElementById("display")
.innerHTML="<a href='#'><img src='images/photo46.jpg'></a>";
var img4 = document.getElementById("display")
.innerHTML="<a href='#'><img src='images/photo47.jpg'></a>";
var img5 = document.getElementById("display")
.innerHTML="<a href='#'><img src='images/photo61.jpg'></a>";
        }
```

But for some reason when the I click on one of the images it only shows the last image in the div container. I am obviously doing something wrong but I feel like I am kind of on the right track. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the last thing that happens in you function?

You need to pass the image you want a parameter e.g.

```
 gallery(1);
```

And the then get you function to show image 1:

```
function gallery(img_num){
  //show image number img_num
}
```

There's many other things I could say about your code about inline javascript etc. but you can google that there are many sites that can explain that.

Answer (score 0):

Put yourself on your program's place: you take the element with id "display" and put into it first photo, then 2nd and so on till the 5th.

Doesn't matter which photo was clicked. You do always the same and take 5th photo in the result.

Comment: So how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help you

Live Demo [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sXbYs/3/)
HTML

```
    <div id="imgs">
     <img  id="imgs1" alt="adf" src="http://i2.wp.com/img.timeinc.net/time/daily/2013/1311 /232_int_afghanistan_1109.jpg?resize=200%2C133">
      <img id="imgs2" src="http://i0.wp.com/img.timeinc.net/time/daily/2013/1311/232_ent_thor_1110.jpg?resize=200%2C133">

      </div>

   <div id="display">

   <div>
```

JQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#imgs1").click(function() {
$("#display").html("<a href='#'><img src='http://timeglobalspin.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/de7f94520e744ada949e8f0759daf783-0.jpg?w=1393'></a>");
     });


     $("#imgs2").click(function() {
$("#display").html("<a href='#'><img src='http://cinepop.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Thor-O-Mundo-Sombrio-4-650x400.jpg'></a>");
     });

 });
```

For Live Demo [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sXbYs/3/)

If this is what you need put a **Reply me..**